# Order by row and limit result in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get a result from the database in a laravel 5 based application and for the life of me can't figure it out.

I want to chose the top 5 results DESC from a row called count.
This is what I have:

```
$full = Fulls::all()->orderBy('count', 'desc')->take(5)->get();
```

I tried plenty of other ways too but nothing seems to work. Now I'm getting an error:

> FatalErrorException in indexController.php line 19: Call to undefined
>   method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::orderBy()

However, anywhere I look I see people working with `orderBy()`, so... what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should use `Fulls::orderBy(..)->take(5)->get()` instead.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to sort/order a collection you can use the sortBy() method.

eg.

```
$full = Fulls::get(); // Get the Fulls collections
$full = $full->sortBy('count')->take(5);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can skip for offset

```
$full = Fulls::orderBy('count', 'desc')->skip(0)->take(5)->get(); //get first 5 rows
$full = Fulls::orderBy('count', 'desc')->skip(5)->take(5)->get(); //get next 5 rows
```

Actual mysql query will look like:

```
SELECT * FROM fulls ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 0,5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `skip` and `take` function of laravel and `orderBy`

```
Fulls::where([['user_id','=',auth()->user()->id]])
                ->where([['title','LIKE',"%".$text_val."%"]])
                ->orderBy('id','DESC')
                ->skip($offset)
                ->take(2)
```